# How can I use music to increase productivity?

Tags: classical-music

How can I use music to increase productivity ??

I listen to music for about half an hour each day and find that it can be very relaxing for my daily schedule but I mostly find that I end up listening to music that is trending at that time.

I want to take it to the next level and as a student I would like to know some ways in which I could use music to increase my productivity in studies (if possible) or release some tension/stress.

For example If listening to some specific genre of music, that could help me (Like classical or something)?? Or 
I use Spotify , so any good radio /playlist , or maybe even a podcast on Spotify.

Mainly I'm looking for something that could either boost productivity or release some tension off my mind

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point would be Spotify's ["Study"](https://open.spotify.com/genre/study-page) or ["Focusing"](https://open.spotify.com/genre/focus-page?) genre, which contain a variety of curated playlists made by Spotify editors.

Since you tagged this question with [classical-music](/questions/tagged/classical-music), you could also take a look at something like ["Study: Classical Concentration"](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/3PXDsvp66pHL3qEbUWv3Fk?si=gJOlobooTUOssO_CLM-72A)

And if you want something completely different, I suggest looking at Lo-Fi Beats that have become popular over the last few months. From anecdotal evidence, they seem to be working quite well for studying.